# Shopping Cart Rule Valid Only If No Other Coupons Active?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I have a "free shipping" Magento shopping cart price rule that is active if the price is over $100.00. I have other coupons on the site, I want to make the free shopping valid only if no other coupon is used. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be acomplished by given the non-shipping coupons a higher priority number under the "rule information" tab and selecting "Stop Further Rule processing" to "Yes" under actions tab.